# Aligning curved object to another's curved object's axis.

Tags: trigonometry, curves

Aligning curved object to another's curved object's axis.

I have several curved objects that I'm trying to get lined up with the axis of a reference curve. I've tried `Vector = Vector2 - Vector1` but for some reason it's not lining up. There's something wrong with my calculations but I'm not sure what.

**Curved Object:**

[image: img1]

When I split the curved object into multiple parts and do `Vector = Vector2 - Vector1`,
The curve to move / align **see blue arrow** doesn't align to the axis of the reference curve **see red arrow**

[image: img2]

What formula am I missing so I can align the curves (**see blue arrow**) to the reference curve (**see red arrow**)?

[image: IMG3]

It should look like this (**see red circles**)

[image: img align]